# Delete Items from ListView in C#

Tags: c#, listview

I need to delete items from a `ListView`, the code I am looking for will show a MessageBox to confirm and if no item is selected it will show an error MessageBox

This is my code and it is not working :(

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems != null)
    {
        var confirmation = MessageBox.Show(
            "Voulez vous vraiment supprimer les stagiaires séléctionnés?",
            "Suppression", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question
        );

        if (confirmation == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (listView1.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    listView1.Items[i].Remove();
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("aucin stagiaire selectionnes", "erreur",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

The error is not in delete but, in `MessageBox's` I have two `MessageBox's`, error must be shown first before confirmation.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your output window?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: i am not getting errors and neither exceptions , i actually can delete items but , but the error is in messageboxs,
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean the error is in the MessageBoxes..? you need to clarify or clean up the question. Re-write the question in regards that pertain to the issue(s) you are currently having

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Start counting from the end going to zero

```
for (int i = listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (listView1.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        listView1.Items[i].Remove();
    }
}
```

However consider that every ListViewItem has an *Index* property and you can use it with the *SelectedItems* collection in such a way to prepare a solution that has the advantages to avoid a redundant test and a loop on lesser number of items.

Also, the SelectedItems collection is never null, if no selection is present, then the collection is empty but not null.

So your code could be rewritten

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    var confirmation = MessageBox.Show("Voulez vous vraiment supprimer les stagiaires séléctionnés?", "Suppression", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (confirmation == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        for (int i = listView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ListViewItem itm = listView1.SelectedItems[i];
            listView1.Items[itm.Index].Remove();
        }
    }
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("aucin stagiaire selectionnes", ...);
```

Comment: the error is not in delete but, in messageboxs  i have two messagesbox, erreur must be shown first before confirmation

Comment: Yes, because you test for null, instead the SelectedItems collection is never null, if no selection is present it is an empty collection

Answer (score 2):

You should not reference the original collection you are using during iteration, but some other:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
   if (item.Selected)
     listView1.Items.Remove(item);
```

Comment: You cannot modify a collection while enumerating it

Comment: @Thelonias, I wrote "some other" collection, but there is none in the answer. `ToList()` can be used to make one before iterating, but [Steve answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15572264/1997232) with indexes going backwards is more optimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
//if (lvPhotos.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
            if (lvPhotos.CheckedIndices.Count > 0)
            {
                var confirmation = MessageBox.Show("Supprimer les photos séléctionnées ?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (confirmation == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    // selected
                    //for (int i = lvPhotos.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    //{
                    //    lvPhotos.Items.RemoveAt(lvPhotos.SelectedIndices[i]);
                    //}

                    // checked
                    for (int i = lvPhotos.CheckedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        lvPhotos.Items.RemoveAt(lvPhotos.CheckedIndices[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just this code without -- decrement

```
listView1.Items[i].Remove();
```

Note : You can also use `RemoteAt method` by specifing position

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your confirmation `MessageBox` from `Show` to `ShowDialog`. This will make it modal and wait for a result.

You need to check for emptry on "SelectedItems"

Comment: i am getting this error (Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox' does not contain a definition for 'ShowDialog' )

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought you were using WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code like this. Note that `ListView.SelectedIndices` collection holds the indexes of the selected `ListViewItems`. Just iterate them from the end towards beginning and you won't need to deal with index updates but leave them to the `for` loop:

```
            if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count>0)
            {
                var confirmation = MessageBox.Show("Voulez vous vraiment supprimer les stagiaires séléctionnés?", "Suppression", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (confirmation == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    for (int i = listView1.SelectedIndices.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {

                        listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[i]);

                    }
                }
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("aucin stagiaire selectionnes", "erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```