# Remove Duplicate items from listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have bound the data to `ListView` from multiple sources. And there is duplicate data, I want to remove all the duplicates from that `ListView`. I used the following code but it is not helping.

```
listview.Sorting = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
for (int i = 0; i < listview.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
   if (listview.Items[i].Tag == listview.Items[i + 1].Tag)
   {
      listview.Items[i + 1].Remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: This should remove duplicate entries, what result this gives?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: By the look of it I can say that you can not modify collection while iterating.  This possibly could throw eception. One suggestion, just grab indexes of the duplicates and remove it separately.

Comment: @prashanth - that would be true if OP was using a `foreach` loop, but they're not.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572169/delete-items-from-listview-in-c-sharp

Comment: This code seems to be working fine.!! Are you getting the values of `Tag` property in the debugger ??

Answer (score 1):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's not possible to know for sure what the problem is. However, most likely your `Tag` values are reference types and not actually identical object instances.

Assuming the objects override the `Equals()` method, you can fix it by using that method instead:

```
listview.Sorting = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
for (int i = 0; i < listview.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
   if (listview.Items[i].Tag.Equals(listview.Items[i + 1].Tag))
   {
      listview.Items[i + 1].Remove();
      i--;
   }
}
```

Note that you also had a bug in which you would skip checking elements if there were three or more duplicates of a given value. You can fix this by decrementing `i` when you remove an element (see above).

Comment: Please note the link I provided. I offered a solution to the most likely error in your code, but frankly...unless you provide a proper code example, a lot of people will have to waste a lot of time before someone randomly stumbles across the correct answer, assuming that ever happens at all. With a proper code example, a solution can be provided easily and quickly (assuming you don't discover it yourself as you prepare the code example).