# Why is my ListViewItem not deleting?

Tags: c#, android, listview, events

I have some code that lets the user add a day (each day is a ListViewItem), and the day is sent to a custom adapter with a delete button. In the adapter , I call an event when the delete button is clicked. The first item I delete deletes with no problem, but for the next one I get a NullReferenceException. Im suspecting it has to do with an incorrect index or something.

This snippet is from the fragment. It recieves the event sent from the adapter. The first item I delete deletes like It's supposed to, but it's the only one.

```
        Adapter1.OnDayDeleted += (o,e) =>
        {               
            Day day = e.Day;
            DM.ListOfDays.Remove(day);
            Adapter1.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            Adapter1 = new Adapters.DayObject(Activity, DM.ListOfDays);
            ListViewDays.Adapter = Adapter1;

            Helpers.Common.SetListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListViewDays);

        };
```

This snippet is from the adapter. It sends an event back to the fragment.

```
        Button buttonRemoveDay = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonRemoveDay);
        buttonRemoveDay.Click += delegate
        {
            var day = myItems[position];

            //Console.WriteLine(day.Name);
            OnDayDeleted.Invoke(this, new OnDayDeletedEventArgs(day));
        };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete Items from ListView in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572169/delete-items-from-listview-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you using Xamarin for IDE ?

Comment: At which line is NullReferenceException thrown? After deleting first element the myItems collection is possibly changed and the position index is possibly not valid any more or shows to an element other than originally intended.

Comment: At `OnDayDeleted.Invoke(...);`

Comment: I followed the link in the comment and its still the same. NullReferenceException at `OnDayDelete.Invoke(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. Just remove the line

`Adapter1 = new Adapters.DayObject(Activity, DM.ListOfDays);`